# new to java. can't refresh applet class file

Tags: java, html, applet

I keep thinking I've found the answer in the "questions that may already have your answer" and then something else weird happens...

I have a .java file on my desktop...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.Applet;

public class MyFirstApplet extends Applet {
public void paint (Graphics g) {
g.drawString("This is my first Applet!!!", 200, 100);
}
}
```

I have an html file on my desktop...

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>My First Applet</TITLE>
<BODY>
<CENTER>
<APPLET CODE = 'MyFirstApplet.class' WIDTH = 300 HEIGHT = 250 BORDER = 3>
</APPLET>
</CENTER>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I compile the .java file. It compiles onto my desktop. I change the coordinates of the drawString. I compile again but nothing changes. I delete the class file completely and it still shows the old file. I clear my browser cache(firefox),reopen the html file, and it still shows the old file. I try various things and once in a while it seems to go to the change I made, but I can't figure out why it does when it does.

My question is - How can I make it so I can easily see the changes in my java code to mess around and learn applets? And if I can add another question(I'm new to this forum, so I'm not sure), where is the browser even pulling this class file from if I've deleted the class file and my browser cache?

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear Java cache and disable it during development

See [How do I clear the Java cache?](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/plugin_cache.xml)  for details.

Comment: +1  Good tip.  I prefer my method though.  If we open an applet page, the console will pop up automatically.

Answer (score 1):

For testing applets I would recommend 3 tools that are not the browser.

1. The [Applet Viewer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/appletviewer.html) provided with the SDK.
2. [Appleteer](http://pscode.org/appleteer/)
3. Make an hybrid application/applet.

None of those testing approaches will cache classes.

As to testing in the browser, sometimes it is necessary.  E.G. the String is supplied by the user via Javascript.  While none of the above listed tools cache classes, they also do not support JS.

When it comes time that you ***must*** move to browser based testing:

1. Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to display for applets and JWS apps.
2. Open the applet page in the browser.
3. In the (now open) console, type `X` to ***clear the class cache*** then refresh the page in the browser (e.g. with `F5`).

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I'm not clear on some things. First, I'll try to keep this to the important stuff, but I want to learn to just do it through the browser for now, but that's good info for later about other ways to test later. Second, the Java Console seems like I'm one step closer, but pressing x doesn't seem to do anything, and even if I go to settings and delete all the temporary internet files through the java console, that doesn't seem to do it either.

Comment: Andrew, I saw you commented on another post that you prefer your method. If it's user error, I apologize, but your method doesn't seem to work. Pressing x does nothing, and deleting temp files through the console isn't doing it either. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong with your method?

Comment: What browser (make & model)?  What OS (M&M)?  What Java (M&M)?

Comment: Firefox 20, Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit, Java 1.7.0_17

Comment: Raise a [bug report](http://bugs.sun.com/) against it (after searching, of course).  Given there are alternatives (one of which I wrote for just this kind of problem), I do not intend to invest more time in this matter.